# What happens if you don't check-in your Flixbus ticket before boarding?

Tags: buses, cancellations, check-in, flixbus

I am currently in a Flixbus bus, but before boarding on the bus I didn't check-in my ticket. The bus arrived a bit late, so everyone was boarding freely without showing the ticket to the driver (conductor) and so did I as a victim of sheep psychology.

Can there be any negative consequences of not checking-in your Flixbus ticket? Like my seat being sold to someone else on the other stops on my way or my return ticket being withdrawn?

Note that I am traveling together with my friend, and my trip is between 2 Schengen countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I travel regularly with Flixbus, and there'll be no issues. A lot of the time I don't even buy a ticket for the whole journey I'm actually making, and I got nervous once, when it got sold out on the section I hadn't paid for, that they might check everyone's tickets and throw me off. Somehow, however, it was sorted out without any issues.

Obviously, since you (presumably) have a valid ticket for the whole trip, there are **no grounds whatsoever** for any problems.

You don't get a specific seat either. So really, you're fine.

Comment: I confirm this answer, as I had no issues during my onward journey and my return ticket was also valid.